# How to repeat a timer that ends with a message box?

Tags: vb.net, loops, timer, messagebox

The purpose of the program is to remind the user to take a break every 30 minutes. The timer also allows the user to input how often to remind them. The countdown works only once when it reaches zero, however, l want to repeat the process three times. Dice images are placeholders. Sorry for any rookie errors.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If lblHrs.Text = "0" And lblMin.Text = "0" And lblSec.Text = "0" Then
        dice1 = Int(Rnd() * 6 + 1)
        Select Case dice1

            Case "1"
                DiceRoll1.Image = My.Resources._1
            Case "2"
                DiceRoll1.Image = My.Resources._2
            Case "3"
                DiceRoll1.Image = My.Resources._3
            Case "4"
                DiceRoll1.Image = My.Resources._4
            Case "5"
                DiceRoll1.Image = My.Resources._5
            Case "6"
                DiceRoll1.Image = My.Resources._6

        End Select
        Timer1.Enabled = False

    End If

    Dim seconds As Double
    Dim minutes As Double
    Dim hours As Double

    Double.TryParse(lblSec.Text, seconds)
    Double.TryParse(lblMin.Text, minutes)
    Double.TryParse(lblHrs.Text, hours)

    If seconds = 0 And minutes <> 0 Then
        lblSec.Text = 59
        lblMin.Text = minutes - 1
    ElseIf seconds > 0 Then
        lblSec.Text = seconds - 1
    End If
    If minutes = 0 And hours <> 0 Then
        lblMin.Text = 59
        lblHrs.Text = hours - 1
    End If

    Dim Msg, Style, Title
    Msg = "Time to rest and exercise."    ' Define message.
    Style = vbOKOnly + vbInformation    ' Define buttons.
    Title = "Rest reminder"    ' Define title.

    ' Display message.
    MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)

End Sub
```

Comment: "loop the timer" is a nonsensical expression. Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: By the way, you really ought to set `Option Strict On` in your project and also in the IDE options, so that it is `On` by default in future. Declaring variables without a type is BAD and having `Option Strict On` will disallow that and various other things that allow you to get yourself into trouble with data types.

Comment: Also, don't access the same property of `My.Resources` over and over. Each time you do, a new object is created. You should get each property value once only and assign the results to variables, then use them over and over. That way, you only create one `Image` object for each picture. You can also `Dispose` those objects explicitly when you're done with them.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm trying to repeat the countdown timer when it reaches zero for an adjustable number of times by using a loop. I don't know where to begin & end the loop since l am a beginner. My teacher didn't explain much and gave most of the code. Although, l watched a number of tutorials, l can't figure it out.

Comment: You appear to be going about this in very much the wrong way. If you want to measure elapsed time then you use a `Stopwatch`. If you want to countdown a time period then you set a `TimeSpan` variable to that period and then subtract the `Elapsed` of the `Stopwatch` from it to see how much time is left. You can use a `Timer` to enable you to display the elapsed or remaining time, which you would do by calling `ToString` on the appropriate `TimeSpan`. If you want to go again when time expires, simply `Restart` the `Stopwatch`. Research the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: Sorry, l wrote in a very confusing way that led to a misunderstanding. The purpose of the program is to remind the user to take a break every 30 minutes. The timer also allows the user to input how often to remind them. The countdown works only once when it reaches zero, however, l want to repeat the process three times. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Are you trying to display the remaining time as it goes down or are you just notifying the user when the time expires?

Comment: Repeat/restart the timer when it ends. The timer works, but l want to have it restart/repeat again.

Comment: If you want to do something three times then you simply increment a variable each time you do something and then stop when it gets to 3. I'm not sure where the actual issue is here.

Comment: A `Timer` just raises its `Tick` event. That's all. Just increment a counter each time it `Ticks` and stop it when you get to 3. Again, what's the actual issue here? Counting doesn't change because you're doing it in code instead of on your fingers.

Comment: The problem is that the timer stops when it reaches zero. It has to go from 5 seconds to 0 seconds and then 5 seconds to 0 seconds again.

Comment: A `Timer` doesn't go to zero. How many times can I say the same thing? A `Timer` raises its `Tick` event. That's it. If you want that `Timer` to `Tick` three times then increment a variable each time it `Ticks` and `Stop` it when that variable gets to 3. I can't keep repeating myself so I'm going to leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer to your question but I wanted to post a chunk of code so a comment was not a good option. This class will help you if you are trying to implement a countdown:

```vb
Public Class CountdownStopwatch
    Inherits Stopwatch

    Public Property Period As TimeSpan

    Public ReadOnly Property Remaining As TimeSpan
        Get
            Dim timeRemaining = Period - Elapsed

            Return If(timeRemaining > TimeSpan.Zero, timeRemaining, TimeSpan.Zero)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsExpired As Boolean
        Get
            Return Elapsed >= Period
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

It's basically a `Stopwatch` with extra countdown functionality. For instance, if you want to do something for 10 minutes then you can do this:

```vb
myCountdownStopwatch.Period = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
myCountDownStopwatch.Restart()
```

In the `Tick` event of your `Timer`, you can display the time remaining and prompt the user when time expires like this:

```vb
timeReaminingLabel.Text = myCountdownStopwatch.Remaining.ToString("m\:ss")

If myCountdownStopwatch.IsExpired Then
    myTimer.Stop()
    myCountdownStopwatch.Stop()
    myCountdownStopwatch.Reset()

    'Prompt user here.
End If
```